# Align Input with Datepicker and text div

Tags: html, input, datepicker, alignment, angular-material

I am trying to build a kind of toolbar (without using `md-toolbar`) consisting of the following parts:

- `input` for search by unique ID
- `datepicker` for search by date
- a `div`, `span`, `label` (or whatever would do the job) to show the number of search results

However, I did not get these three elements aligned properly.

This is my code:

```
<md-content flex layout-padding>
    <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <div class="md-headline">Simulationen</div>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-content>
            <div layout="row">
                <md-input-container layout="row" flex="75">
                    <label><span class="fa fa-search"> </span>Suche nach ID</label>
                    <input ng-model="simSearch.input">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-datepicker ng-model="simSearch.date" md-placeholder="Datum wählen"></md-datepicker>
                <div flex="20">Number of search results</div>
            </div>
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</md-content>
```

In order to make this available to anyone, I set up a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbwWKE?editors=1000).
I did not use any custom CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `layout-align` and adjust the `flex` values - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/PzjJLY?editors=1000)

Markup

```
<md-card-content>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
        <md-input-container layout="row" flex="30">
            <label><span class="fa fa-search"> </span>Search by ID</label>
            <input ng-model="idSearch.input">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-datepicker flex="40" ng-model="idSearch.date" md-placeholder="choose date"></md-datepicker>
        <div flex="30">Number of search results</div>
    </div>
</md-card-content>
```

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment

Use the following for different screen sizes:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children